# TableViewController not updating after editing data and saving. Only updates upon application restart

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm currently making an application that can edit the information stored in certain table view cells by clicking on them and then going to a separate view controller.

Once the changes are made, a save button is pressed, and the fields are updated on parse.com
My issue is that once I go back to my main tableViewController, the table cells aren't updating unless I completely restart the application, at which point everything shows as updated.

I've called the [self.tableView reloadData] method like in the iOS tutorials, but it just won't seem to update.

Here's the .m file for the controller that I'm trying to update.

```
@interface ProspectsTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation ProspectsTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Prospect"];
    [query orderByAscending:@"prospectName"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error in prospect cells");
        }
        else {
            self.allProspects = objects;
            NSLog(@"%@", self.allProspects);
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }];

}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.allProspects count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ProspectCell";
    UITableViewCell *prospectCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    PFObject *prospect = [self.allProspects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    prospectCell.textLabel.text = prospect[@"prospectName"];

    return prospectCell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSLog(@"cell pressed");
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showProspectInfo" sender:cell];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showProspectInfo"]) {

        ProspectInfoViewController *transferViewController = segue.destinationViewController; //prepares an instance of the prospectsTableViewController so we can pass our information over to the next view controller
        PFObject *prospect = self.allProspects[self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row]; //selects the information from the prospect at the cell tapped on
        transferViewController.name = prospect[@"prospectName"];
        transferViewController.phone = prospect[@"phoneNumber"];
        transferViewController.email = prospect[@"email"];
        transferViewController.objectId = [prospect objectId];
    }
}


@end
```

any ideas? I've been trying to figure this one out for quite some time now

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're calling `[self.tableView reloadData];` after coming back to the table view controller. Try adding this to your table view controller's implementation to refresh your table view whenever your view controller is about to appear:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, however it turns out that I also had to reload my data from parse.com in the viewWillAppear method as well. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem! Although I find it interesting that you had to also reload your data from Parse... I thought changes made to PFObjects were immediate (locally, that is). Oh well, glad this helped!

Answer (score 0):

try `reloadData` in `viewDidAppear`

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewDidAppear:animated];
   [self.tableView reloadData]
}
```